# How to prevent tile caching on ol.layer.Tile on data that is Live (WMS TileArcGISRest etc)

Tags: openlayers-3

I've tried this

```html
layer_info.ol_layer.getSource().setTileLoadFunction(function (img, src) {
  img.getImage().src = src + "&seq=" + (new Date()).getTime();
});
```

but it only changes the params on the first call and all subsequent calls just use the cached tiles.

Strangely When Using this on an Image source like Mapguide it works wonderfully and requests a new image every time.

```html
opLayer.getSource().setImageLoadFunction(function(img, src){
  img.getImage().src = src + "&seq=" + (new Date()).getTime();
});
```

EDIT: Here is the full layer before it is pushed in.

```
layer_info.ol_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
opacity: 1 - (conf_layer.transparency / 100),
style: layer_info.display_name,
source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    attributions: [new ol.Attribution({html: conf_layer.attribution})],
    //cacheSize: 0,
    crossOrigin: (conf_layer.crossOrigin != 'null') ?  conf_layer.crossOrigin :  null,
    url: conf_layer.url,
    projection: Model.Projection,
    params: {'LAYERS': conf_layer.layers}
})
```

});
I've discovered that setting cacheSize zero makes it ignore caching, however that only works on layers that aren't being reprojected. I need this layer to be reprojected and always request new tiles when zoomed or panned. (background data is somewhat live, in my arcgis layer it is live)

Comment: You might want to add more code to your post..How is `ol.source.layer` defined? Do you call `source.clear()` to remove all data which fires the loader function??

Comment: Usually you can use default configuration of cache and everything, and all you do when you want to refresh the layer is call `source.updateParams({seq: (new Date()).getTime()});` (if your server sends cache headers that indicates tiles do not invalidate immediately). This requires a reasonably recent version of OpenLayers (3.18.x), because it was fixed not too long ago.

Comment: I used that in my imageLoadFunction source.updateParams({seq: (new Date()).getTime()}); and it only ever ran one time. How can I just add the layer and tell it to never cache? I am on the latest release. This very same line works on Mapguide perfectly but my mapguide is a single image and not tiles.

Comment: @ahocevar This works in Mapguide reprojected  to force refresh always but does not work on tiles reprojected: opLayer.getSource().setImageLoadFunction(function(img, src){
img.getImage().src = src + "&seq=" + (new Date()).getTime();});